# Linux server swappiness

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, centos

I noticed that our server swap is at `Swap Used     98.66% (1,973,240 of 2,000,000)`.  Any tips to reducing this. Just for background I have a

```
 CentOs 6.6 Rack Server
 1.92 (24 core) processors
 48Gig ram
```

We do some very heavy database (MySql) work with it, which resides on a `240gig SSD`.  We also do a lot of file writes for example I had to fix a few things today because we were using 99% of `2Tb main drives`, we also have `160gb SSD` for writing report files.  It's typically at `73%` ram usage and `300% cpu usage`.  So any help would be wonderful.   Like I said we do a ton of work with it. For example around `5.2Gb` of database traffic an hour.

Opps, thought I put this on serverfault, I don't see a way to move it?

Thanks,

Comment: In addition to memory tuning for MySQL, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265713/how-to-configure-swappiness-in-linux-memory-management

Comment: @Nemo - this question is like 3 years old, we've sense changed servers, we use mongoDB for this data now, etc. etc.  It's what happens when you have 120million rows in MySql.  I appreciate the comment, but at this point it's anecdotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL performs terribly when swapping.

48GB -- what is taking that?  Is it mostly MySQL?  If so, lets look at how to decrease the caches in MySQL to avoid swapping.

If you are using InnoDB, set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* ram.  And `key_buffer_size` to 20M.

If you are using MyISAM; well, don't.  (I will elaborate if needed.)

73% RAM sounds like you are not really swapping.

300% CPU sounds like you have some non-MySQL applications that are CPU-bound, or you have some slow queries.  If the latter, let's see them; we may be able to improve them.

Comment: We use both InnoDB and MyIsam,  we have mysql 5.5 with no full text search, the buffer pool is set to 30GB, key buffer is set to 1.5GB.  This is a Dedicated server, so we do have offsite management of it.  They said `35G actual usage` and `if your server is actively writing to swap, and its not.`, I do the setup on it mostly but we do have support from them.  I think it could have been due to the high disk usage that was at 99% of 2T used, I trimmed that down to 47%.  Checking right now it's actually at `100% (2,000,000 of 2,000,000)` this is through whm so maybe that is just wonky

Comment: It's possible  too that if that lags behind then we might be hitting 100% at peak usage times.   Dose that seem pl usable? Also i really appreciate your time.  No need to elaborate about MyISAM, it's used out of necessity, well tell I get around to setting up something like Sphinx, full text is a must, we do millions of full text queries, there is no way around it, as I cant install updated MySql ( semi-managed thing ).  I probably could, but they wouldn't give us support on it.

Comment: The 300% is because of csv files, what we do is let clients search or database we aggregate ( I cant give specifics ), they do this with csv files some on the order of millions of rows from this we generate millions of rows of reports.  I recently rebuilt it with RabbitMq, and a map reduce style setup ( not entirely happy with it yet ).  While there is always room for improvement I would say I am at least on the low end of the Expert level for PHP/MySql/Jquery.  I may be adding Sphinx and Casandra ( for reducing ) soon, and going from file chunks to individual rows.

Comment: Ugg this is so long, actually I was dumping about 1TB of junk/old  files when I looked at that.  So that might be why it so much.

Comment: Is the "Swap used" in bytes (2MB)?  KB (2GB)?  OS Pages (8GB)? or some other unit?

Comment: It's not specified, I just got it from WHM, this is all it says `Swap 100% (2,000,000 of 2,000,000)`.  I know what you are thinking one of those GUI guys, In my own defense I  did set up CHROOT for our clients with no shell access, which meant we had to migrate from CentOs5.5, so I am like intermediate (or learning ) server administration.  I assumed it was GB but give me a few minutes I'll see if they state it in the help or documentation.  Stupid slow VPS + remote desktop, sorry bout the typing.

Comment: Doesn't really say. https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1148Docs/Service+Status  So I assumed it was = 2GB, which sounded  about right.  For the lower memory we had when we first set it up (.16GB )